# how to change background colour in a new window?

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to generate a new window when I receive an interruption. I created this new window and I have the size and title I want, the problem is the background color. I do not know why the new window does not change its color.anyone knows what happen?

```
 def ventanaSTL(self):

    self.frame2 = QFrame()#clase basica para tener un cuadro
    self.v2 = QVBoxLayout()# This class is used to construct vertical box layout objects
    self.vtkWidget2 = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame2)#definimos un interactuador render
    self.v2.addWidget(self.vtkWidget2)

    STLrender_window = self.vtkWidget2.GetRenderWindow()
    STLinteractor = STLrender_window.GetInteractor()

    self.ventana=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ventana.setGeometry(900, 100, 800, 400)
    self.ventana.setWindowTitle('Visualizador STL')


    for i in range(1) :#dos renders

        self.r2 = vtk.vtkRenderer()#determinamos render          
        self.r2.SetBackground(0.8, 0.1, 0.8)#color del fondo            
        self.r2.SetViewport(0, 0, 1, 1)
        STLrender_window.AddRenderer(self.r2)

    STLrender_window.Render()         
    STLinteractor.Initialize()
    STLinteractor.Start()
    self.ventana.show()
```

in fact if I print de render I obtain the background value that i want.
[image]

Comment: Please post a full working example so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I agree - the key here is a full working example. I would also suggest the user tries to use the following example. https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/GeometricObjects/Display/Cone Set the Background after adding the renderer to the render window not before.